# Helm tpl template yaml object without using a string

Tags: templates, yaml, kubernetes-helm, argocd

Heaving some trouble getting something to work in the [argo-helm](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm) helm chart.

I am trying to make use of the very conveinet [extraObjects](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/5687377d8ff4bcd8095207a1480dbbff13d7e117/charts/argo-cd/values.yaml#L431) value in their argo-cd chart.

## Setup

`values.yaml`

```yaml
extraObjects:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      labels: "{{ include `argo-cd.labels` (dict `context` . `component` `configmap`  `name`  `some-config-map`) | nindent 4 | trim }}"
      name: some-config-map
    data:
      something: something
```

`template/extra-manifests.yaml`

```yaml
{{ range .Values.extraObjects }}
---
{{ tpl (toYaml .) $ }}
{{ end }}
```

## Result

sadly it will produce

```yaml
# Source: argo-cd/templates/extra-manifests.yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  something: something
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels: '
    helm.sh/chart: argo-cd-5.19.12
    app.kubernetes.io/name: some-config-map
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: argocd
    app.kubernetes.io/component: configmap
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd'
  name: some-config-map
---
```

## The problem

This is unsurprising really. We put the template into a string so it makes sense that we see a string with the templated content.

I want the template to "float" on the `labels` field. But I can't do that because `{{ blablaba }}` isnt a vaild yaml object.
(Or it is but {} is [object notation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#generic-mapping))

Because they are using the `toYaml` function to turn a valid YAML object into a string for use in the `tpl` function, I can't represent the template any other way other than using the string.

## What I've tried

### Comment Trick?

```yaml
labels: # {{ include `argo-cd.labels` (dict `context` . `component` `configmap`  `name`  `some-config-map`) | nindent 4 | trim }}
```

Thought becuse of the `nindent` it could insert the labels under the comment but it must be striped by `toYaml` or `helm` when the values used

### Yaml `!!map`

```yaml
labels: !!map |
  {{ include `argo-cd.labels` (dict `context` . `component` `configmap`  `name`  `some-config-map`) | nindent 4 | trim }}
```

and

```yaml
labels: !!map |
  {{ include `argo-cd.labels` (dict `context` . `component` `configmap`  `name`  `some-config-map`) | fromYaml }}
```

I don't think yaml has built in conversion but it was worth a shot.

### Yaml `!!yaml`

Tried to play around with [`!!yaml`](https://yaml.org/type/yaml.html) but I don't understand what it's supposed to do.

Tried this:

```yaml
labels:
  !!yaml: '!' : '!map'
  !!value = : {{ include `argo-cd.labels` (dict `context` . `component` `configmap`  `name`  `some-config-map`) | nindent 4 | trim }}
```

and

```yaml
labels:
  !!yaml: '!' : '!map'
  !!value = : {{ include `argo-cd.labels` (dict `context` . `component` `configmap`  `name`  `some-config-map`) | fromYaml }}
```

## Question

Is there any valid YAML notation or object I can use to pass the template through `toYaml` without using a string?

Is there anyway to represent `{{ blabla }}` in YAML without using a string?

## The Correct Way

Obviously doing away with `toYaml` and using strings will result in the expected behavior

```yaml
extraObjects:
  - |
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: ConfigMap
      metadata:
        labels: 
          {{ include `argo-cd.labels` (dict `context` . `component` `configmap`  `name`  `some-config-map`) | nindent 4 | trim }}
        name: some-config-map
      data:
        something: something
```

```yaml
{{ range .Values.extraObjects }}
---
{{ tpl . $ }}
{{ end }}
```

Before I open an issue with the Argo-CD Helm team I just want to know if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know this dirty trick:

```yaml
customServiceTemplate: |
    {{- define "extraService" -}}
    Service'
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: {{ .fullName }}-{{ .serviceName }}
    spec:
      type: LoadBalancer
    # '¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    {{- end }}
    {{- $serviceConfig := dict -}}
    {{- $serviceConfig := merge $serviceConfig .Values.service-}}
    {{- $_ := set $serviceConfig "serviceName" "extra-service" -}}
    {{- $_ := set $serviceConfig "fullName" (include "x.fullname" .) -}}
    {{- $_ := set $serviceConfig "namespace" (include "x.namespace" .) -}}
    {{- include "extraService" $serviceConfig -}}

extraObjects:
  - kind: "{{ tpl .Values.customServiceTemplate . }}"
```

It's rendered as

```yaml
---
# Source: xchart/templates/extraManifests.yaml
kind: 'Service'
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kong-edge-dp-kong-v1-stream-proxy
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
# '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'
```